# How and where does one (optimally) convert POST/GET variables to numbers in Express.js?

Tags: javascript, express, post, get

It's been a while since I've worked with Express and although I used it a fair amount, I'm suddenly drawing a blank on a fairly basic question.

Let's say I'm receiving a number of POST variables in Express, for example, `apples` and `oranges`.  If I

`app.use(express.urlencoded())`

these will arrive as strings on `req.body`, if I recall correctly, thus

```
const {body: {apples, oranges}} = req
```

I need to convert them back to integers.  Should I just do this in the route and then pass them as integers on to the rest of the logic (which I keep separate from the route)?  Or is this not a 'best practice', and I should just pass them on further to convert them elsewhere?  Or does it matter at all?

More importantly, what's the 'best' way to do this?  I settled for

`parseInt(apples,10)`

but would something as simple as

`+apples`

work just as well?

Comment: How you use your parameters, and what data types they should be, is up to you. Technically, `+apples` is the most efficient way to convert to a number, but that's talking about micro-optimizations at that point, as basically all methods of casting should be practically the same. (`+apples`, `parseInt(apples)`, `parseFloat(apples)`, `apples * 1`, `Number(apples)`, etc.)

Comment: And regardless of how you convert will need to validate they aren't NaN

Comment: When were they integers?